# Cocoa Obj-C : How make Searchfield with gradient background?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nssearchfield

According to Apple human interface guidelines, the recommended way of puting all controls acting on an item view (e.g. a tableview) is make an alignment of gradient buttons below the tableview. In my project, this should include a searchfield which, like other controls, should have a gradient background. I can see that for example in Xcode 4 in the left lower corner where one can filter the list of the project items.

But when I explore the methods of NSSearchField, I see no way of specifying a gradient background. So how can I do this ?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: How is this related to cocoa-design-pattern?

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have picked that tag. I removed it. Do you feel better?

Comment: I think your timing of question was wrong. Please delete this question and ask again, a lot of people will see it **now**.

Comment: Not if you keep putting your remarks the way you're putting them.

Comment: ok, sorry if you got hurt by my words :(

Comment: I posted a question politely, even thanking people in advance for their questions. Accidentally, I added a tag which was not suitable. You mentioned it in a way which I found quite pretentious and not even a useful reply for this message. Anyway I corrected my tags and even said 'sorry'. I wrote "do you feel better" in an ironic way but you didn't catch the humorous aspect. Sorry again. Now that we understood each other better, can you just remove all our comments and unlock my question so we can go forward with this IT issue? Thanks.

Comment: provide the link here,

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
     NSGradient* g = [[[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:color1 endingColor:color2]];
    [g drawInRect:[self bounds] angle:a];
    ...
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

?